# How to get specific value from sub-document in mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, rest

I want to find the specific field value from mongo sub-document, but its retrieving either full data or null value. I am using mongo 3.0.1 driver. Is there any issue with the syntax for the mongo specific driver.
Json data is:

```
    {
        "Demo": {
            "Demo Data": {
                "Building": {
                    "A": 1,
                    "B": 2,
                    "C": 3,
                    "D": 4,

                },
                "Mode": "Building"
            }
        }
    }
```

The code is as below:

```
 DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("demo");
                    BasicDBObject field = new BasicDBObject();
                    BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
                    field1.put("_id", 0);
                    field1.put("Demo", 1);
                    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(document, field);
                    BasicDBObject object = new BasicDBObject();
                    BasicDBObject Mode = new BasicDBObject();
                    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                        object = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
                        Mode.put("Mode", object.get(Mode));
                        System.out.println("Mode value is"+Mode);

                    }
```

but using above code, the output showing as:

```
Mode value is {"Mode":null}
```

The requirement is to get the following output:
         `{"Mode": "Building"}`.

Please specify where the condition went wrong. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which version of Mongo Java driver is being used?

Comment: @CS_noob: I am using version mongo-3.0.1 java driver

Answer (score 0):

I think you are incorrectly assuming that since you have put `field1.put("Demo", 1);` , it would return you inner document, whereas no matter what it would always return you full document what it will do is omit other fields, but even then it would be full document which is right from the root.

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  object = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
  Map map = object.toMap();
  Mode.put("Mode", map.get("Demo").get("Demo Data").get("Mode")); //pre-check for NPE
  System.out.println("Mode value is"+Mode);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but I am wondering if there is any way in mongo to search the particular sub-document in a single call/method without nesting the get methods?

Comment: mongo driver will always return the full document, if you mean to get it without changing it into map, I think you will have to try some hit and trial maybe object.get("Demo.Demo Data.Mode"), however I doubt it since this is specific to the driver implementation.